# Secondary Monitor Goes off upon logging in

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, dell, display, monitor

I am using **dell xps 14z laptop with Ubuntu 12.04**, when booting up it detects the secondary monitor [Viewsonic] but upon entering the username/password , the secondary monitor goes blank . when I open system settings  --> Displays , it does not even detect the secondary monitor which it detected initially , what could be the problem and how do i debug this ?

THanks,

Praveen

Comment: Did detect displays work?

Comment: no it doesnt display when I run xrandr as a sudo , let me know wat can be done as the monitor works perfectly fine with another laptop [dell inspiron]   , this is the output http://pastebin.com/q0nPUECr

Answer (score 0):

With root privileged try `xrandr --auto` then type `xrandr`. Does it show two screens then? (on the console)

Comment: no it doesnt display when I run xrandr as a sudo , let me know wat can be done as the monitor works perfectly fine with another laptop [dell inspiron] , this is the output  http://pastebin.com/q0nPUECr

Comment: Do you have hybird graphics? (eg. Intel & nVidia) If so, then what card are you using at the moment when you run xrandr? There can be several issues why it is not working, nvidia optimus has/had some problems previously. Take a look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee maybe that can help you.

Comment: THis model of xps 14z is not  hybrid as it has only intel from the lspci, I am connecting from the laptop HDMI to the monitor which has a hdmi to dvi adapter . this worksed perfectly for a dell inspiron laptop thus i concluded that the monitor is fine and also the hdmi cable / HDMI DVI adapter       :                                                                                        praveen@praveen-XPS:~$ sudo lspci  | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: That is indeed very strange. Can you please post your `Xorg.log` and `dmesg` output? Also double-check the graphic related bios settings. Perhaps you could also try to use another connector for the external screen if you have a DisplayPort adapter.

Comment: hi ortang  ,  Here are the files you requested , uploaded to droplr   : Dmesg http://d.pr/f/LaS1 and Xorg http://d.pr/f/rmkh    , this laptop has a mini display port and I dont have the mini display port to VGA adapter as I am using the HDMI to HDMI which in turn connects to the viewsonic monitor through the HDMI to DVI port. I will try to get it soon. thanks again for your help